# How can i create font family from assets folder?

Tags: android

I want load my fonts from assets folder to my font resource xml file

In fact, I want something like @asset for load it.

[image]

font-family1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@asset/fontOne/a" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@asset/fontOne/a_italic" />
</font-family>
```

Comment: You can use `Typeface` to to do this

Comment: @Gourav I want this for xml. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: check if the subfolder is supported if not just use it as per the documentation e.g.  android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"
I am not sure subfolder will give you a good structure to your codebase (if this is your point) as nobody what too many fonts file in their application as it might be a heavy resource.

Comment: @Killer subfolder only support for assets folder! "@font" not support subfolder. you don't have any other way?

Comment: @Zardchoobe this approach is not gonna help you! I recommend using the `@font/fontName` method. But tell me one thing why do you want to do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your font to all texts, use [caligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library.
And if you want to set your font to specific text, use `TypeFace` instead.

Comment: I want standard way: I want standard way: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: Without any libraries

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `.ttf` files inside a subfolder in assets folder and then you can load them but I recommend using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) as it makes everything much easier and cleaner.

Comment: I want standard way: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml

Comment: Without any libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own font class

```
final class FontsOverride {

    static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                               String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    private static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                    final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and inside your `Application` `Class`

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "fontOne/a.ttf");
    }
```

And inisde your style

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/main_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```